# react native conditional rendering with section list and flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have two different components one is `CategoryList` which is a flatlist and `regionlist` is a section list. I would like to display the `CategoryList` first and when item clicked the regionlist will show however I m not sure why it is not working. (I use context to store the state)

```
{!isToggle ? (
    <CategoryList></CategoryList>
  ) : (
    <RegionList style={styles.regionListStyle}></RegionList>
  )}
```

I also create a button to see if it is a problem about the context but it is not.

```
const ToggleContext = createContext(true);

export const useToggle = () => {
return useContext(ToggleContext);
};

export function ToggleProvideData({children}) {
const [isToggle, setToggle] = useState(true)

return <ToggleContext.Provider value={{isToggle,setToggle}}>
        {children}
        </ToggleContext.Provider>;
}
```

I just wonder conditional render is it not working for flatlist?

UPDATE: I tried create a state to store the useContext `isToggle` but it only appears for like 1 sec

Comment: which type of this `isToggle` variable ?

Comment: try to do console.log(isToggle) and check if it ever gets to 'true'

Comment: i updated the context which it store the state

Answer (score 1):

I guess isToggle as a boolean variable, hence you can use the below code for rendering conditionally

```
{ (isToggle === true) &&
    <CategoryList></CategoryList>
}

{ (isToggle === false) &&
    <RegionList style={styles.regionListStyle}></RegionList>
}
```